# How to add XML to processing game

Tags: android, xml, processing

So I am making an `Android` game in `Processing` and in order for my game to be playable (Screen Sizes) on all devices I have to, if I'm correctly aware, add `XML` to my game, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: The phrase "add XML to my game" doesn't really mean much by itself. What exactly are you trying to do? What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: @KevinWorkman Ah, sorry about that. Wasn't sure how to word it, well. I was looking at this: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html And I saw that it needed XML, so I was wondering how would I be able to do what it shows, on processing.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're talking about are just layout files. You don't really need to use them with Processing, since Processing will just take up the entire screen.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Ah yes, seems like it. So does that mean, that if I just put in size(displayWidth, displayHeight); And keep on doing what I'm doing, it should work for all phones? Can i still use numbers for x and y positions or would I have to do something like displayWidth/2, etc. ?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking, but generally should should position things relative to the width and height of the window, unless you can guarantee the size of the window ahead of time. And if you're targeting different sizes of phone, then you can't guarantee that. Think about what would happen on desktop if you changed the size of the window.

Comment: Ah okay, so it's generally better to use things relative to the width/height, thankyou! I'll try it out soon.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Is it possible to do something like this: '   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR); ' in Processing? So that they are not able to rotate their screen.

Comment: You really might want to try posting multiple questions, or better yet googling this stuff. This is the first result for googling "processing android screen orientation": https://github.com/processing/processing-android/wiki#Screen_Orientation_and_the_size_command and says you can use orientation(PORTRAIT); or oritentation(LANDSCAPE); to set the rotation.

Comment: Wow. There's tons of useful information on there which I just skipped past, when i was trying to find out how to do the size thing for android, I always got that website and kinda just quickly scrolled through it and thought not much of it, but now that I'm looking a bit more in-depth, it's very useful. Thankyou!

Comment: @KevinWorkman Hey, I was trying some stuff out, trying to get my buttons to be aligned properly, but whenever I try it out on my phone, it's always to the left/right, etc. And thus, them not being clickable in the right position, would you know how to fix this?

Comment: It's really hard to help you without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you either edit your post or make a new one with an MCVE showing what you're doing? Maybe create a computer (not Android) program that shows buttons, then resize the frame to test different sizes?